# Get data from a table along with concatanated data from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables in Mysql:

> Products with columns |ID|Name|,
>   Tags with columns also
>   |ID|Name| and the third one is 
>  ProductTagsRelations with
>   |ID|prodID|tagID|.

This third one contains rows with product ID's and every tag they're linked to.
Can I get all the data from the Products table with every tag related to each one of them from the Tags table, in a single string or whatever, all in one query?

Comment: Yes. See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by joining the tables and grouping on product:

```
select 
  p.id, p.name,
  group_concat(t.name order by t.name) tags
from Products p
left join ProductTagsRelations r on r.prodid = p.id
left join Tags t on t.id = r.tagid
group by p.id, p.name
```

With [`group_concat()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) you get a list of the tags of each product.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51jG1KmLAVEXLTgAYups1X/0).

Comment: Wow this is complicated. But it absolutely works. Those 2 left joins are necessary right?

Comment: All table must be joined, so they are necessary. I used left joins instead of inner joins just in case there is a product without any tags at all.

Comment: I guess `Categories` is a table's name so `p.ID=Categories` is invalid and syntactically wrong.

Comment: Can I ask why we have to group_by two columns?

Comment: You can group by id only, but in this case select p.name would be (although mysql allows it) not guaranteed to be correct. The SQL standard is that in the select statement you must include only columns included in `group by` and aggregated columns like max, sum, count etc. In this case id with name are unique combinations, so I included both.

Comment: Do you know if I can add `WHERE p.Name LIKE "%..%"` after the group by?

Comment: *Before* the group by, yes you can.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193479/discussion-between-yannisp-and-forpas).